# Amazon SES API quotas of SendBulkTemplatedEmail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I know that the destination of the SendBulkTemplatedEmail method can include up to 50 email addresses.
So if I have more than 50 destinations, I will need to call this method several times.

However, according to the documentation, the Amazon SES API also has the following limitations.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/quotas.html#quotas-email-general

> 【Resource】 Rate at which you can call Amazon SES API actions
> 【Default Quota】 All actions (except for SendEmail, SendRawEmail, and SendTemplatedEmail) are throttled at one request per second.

Does all this mean that even if the Sending Rate is more than 50, the SendBulkTemplatedEmail method can only send a maximum of 50 emails per second?

Or does the SendTemplatedEmail in this document mean that SendBulkTemplatedEmail is treated the same way?

As the method is to send emails by bulk, it is very disappointing that it can only send up to 50 emails per second.
I understand that the Sending Rate will be limited, but I do not want the API quota limit to be affected.